# переключение между табами

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Есть tabbedpage с четырьмя вкладками, на одной из вкладок(допустим на первой) есть кнопка с событием, вопрос в том как этой кнопкой переключить CurrentPage на любую другую, и как мне вообще передать объект со свойством CurrentPage, в событие этой кнопки.

Comment: я получил tabbed page через (this.Parent as TabbedPage).CurrentPage = ?

Comment: и я добился результата вот так (this.Parent as TabbedPage).CurrentPage=(Parent as TabbedPage).Children[2]; но я хотел бы узнать более нормальный способ